# What software can extract data from image plots and output in array format?

Tags: image, plot, graph, gnn

tl;dr extracting data from image plots to data arrays

Hello all,

I am currently looking for software (either open source code or commercial software) that receives as an input an image (.jpg or .png for example) of a graph plot (for example the plot below) and can automatically analyze the plot without user input and output an array for numerical data derived from the graph (say in .xlsx format).

[example plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xuf6.png)

So I would want an array of data consisting of 7 columns (one for each curve), and X rows containing the data of all the plots after the software scans the image plot. I assume this is done using ANN's but not exactly sure.

Thanks in advance

I looked for open-source as well as commercial software with no luck